# Overlay semi transparent heatmap to image using GUIDE

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I am trying to create a heatmap using the surf command and then overlaying it over an image. I tried resizing the picture and 'converting' cm to pixels so that the image and the heatmap will have the same units ( I multiplied by 96 and divided by 2.56 the values in cm) . But when i execute my code, the heatmap appears small in a corner and the image takes the whole area. Could you please help me improve my code so that i can overlay heatmap and image?( S is my matrix for creating the heatmap)

[image]

Thank you in advance :)
My code is:

```
          `axes=handles.body;
          xlim([0 (L.*96)/2.56]); %Length
          ylim([0 (W.*96)/2.56]); %Width
          img=imread('thigh1.jpg');
          img=imresize(img, [(L.*96)/2.56 (W.*96)/2.56]);
          I=image(img); 
          hold (handles.body,'on');
          s=(S.*96)/2.56;
       surf(s,'FaceAlpha','interp','AlphaDataMapping','scaled','AlphaData',gradient(s),'FaceColor','interp');
            view(0,90);  
            hold (handles.body,'off');  
            I.AlphaData=0.5;`
```

Comment: Where does `S` come from? What is the size of `S`? Why are you multiplying it by the same factor with which you rescale your image?

Comment: S is the matrix I used to create a surface (and then a heatmap). S is a 30 by 20 matrix. The heatmap appears small so i thought that by converting I could maybe overlay the image and the heatmap....